# Guice caused throwing UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, guice

I would like to use Guice in my application but it throws following exception when I want to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

When I wrap `main()` function with try... catch block I receive folloving stackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2047)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3869)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3873)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4798)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4804)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements.forMember(StackTraceElements.java:71)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatSource(Messages.java:241)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatSource(Messages.java:220)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatMessages(Messages.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:396)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:485)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2788)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:897)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Throwable.java:752)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:659)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:648)
    at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:639)
    at com.github.blackjack.Main.main(Main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:143)
    at com.google.inject.internal.asm.$ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:418)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.LineNumbers.<init>(LineNumbers.java:64)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:49)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.StackTraceElements$1.load(StackTraceElements.java:45)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3443)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2169)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2128)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2041)
    ... 18 more
```

From the information I found this exception was caused by method contains a lambda definition, is thrown by Provides method. Nevertheless it should be fixed with Guice 4.0. Maybe someone know how to fix it and can help?
Thanks in advance!

`main()` function:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    try{
        MainModule module = new MainModule();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);

        GameFactory gameFactory = injector.getInstance(GameFactory.class);
        DeckFactory blackjackDeckFactory = injector.getInstance(BlackjackDeckCreator.class);
        PlayerFactory playerFactory = injector.getInstance(PlayerFactory.class);

        Player player = playerFactory.createPlayer("Paul");
        Player dealer = playerFactory.createPlayer("Dealer", true);

        Deck deck = blackjackDeckFactory.createDeck();

        Game game = gameFactory.createGame(player, dealer, deck);
        game.start();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); // line 31
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, you could share with us that "main" function

Comment: Sure, just edited the post

Comment: What about line 31? could you mark it on the question?

Comment: Line 31 is not include in the code above, but it was `exception.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: I can't see the big picture. Please add the code related to that stackTrace printing

Comment: Can you please tell Java version you are using? Java 9+ is breaking most of things

Comment: I use Java 10, but also tried 8 and 9. Nothing helped.

Comment: which version of guice are you using?

Comment: I'm using Guice 4.2.0

Answer (score 3):

> I use Java 10, but also tried 8 and 9. Nothing helped.

I think you didn't use Java 8 or 9 because the exception is thrown from `ClassReader` due to using Java version 10 or later .

https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/blob/f7f44a8e306dd2bd70f0db50194f6366938579c5/src/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java#L160

`Opcodes.V9` means Java 9. So please check your Java version again and run with Java 9 or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is an old post. Posting the solution here for visibility -

The issue should be JDK11 incompatibility with GoogleGuice 4.0.

Guice 4.0 does not support Java 9 (or above), but Guice 4.2 does. So, you should add an explicit dependency on GoogleGuice-4.2, and everything should work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JDK9 and above upgrade GoogleGuice version to 4.2 or above. I would suggest >5.
It would show the actual underlying problems such as missing bindings or missing implementations. Hope this helps.